# How to un-highlight menu item and highlight another once new item is selected in Jquery Menu UI

Tags: jquery-ui, menu

I have a jquery UI menu in which I want to highlight a selected item and then un-highlight it once another item has been clicked and highlighted. I got as far as changing the css background color property once the select event is detected on the menu, but before that happens I want to check all items to see if a previous selection is still highlighted, unhighlight it, and THEN highlight the new selection.

```
 <script>
     $(function(){
        $(".menu").menu({

          //detect select event 

            select:function( event, ui ) {

            //highlight the selected menu item

                ui.item.css('background-color','red');

                }

               });

          });
    </script>

//The Menu

 <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#"><h2> Fitness</h2></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><h2> Literature</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><h2>Music</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><h2>Fine Art</h2></a></li>         
            <li><a href="#"><h2>Food</h2></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a css class and adding/removing the class, rather than setting the style directly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".menu").menu({
    select: function (event, ui) {
      $('.selected', this).removeClass('selected');
      ui.item.addClass('selected');
    }
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.menu .ui-menu-item.selected { 
  background-color : red;
}
```

And add this if you want it to stay red even when the item has focus or has a submenu and is active.

```
.menu .ui-menu-item.selected > .ui-state-focus,
.menu .ui-menu-item.selected > .ui-state-active {
  background-color : red ;
  background-image: none;
}
```

You may need to tweek this some more if you plan to have submenus to get it to work in a way that makes sense.

Without submenus: http://jsfiddle.net/sgearhart2/Fba6L/4/

With submenus: http://jsfiddle.net/sgearhart2/Fba6L/5/